# Why try ... except block is not working here

Tags: try-catch, freepascal

I am trying to run following code with try.. except block:

```
program TriangleArea;
uses crt, sysutils;
type 
    num = real; 
var
  a, b, c, s, area : num; 
begin
    write('Enter lengths of 3 sides (separated by spaces): '); 
    try
        readln (a, b, c);
        s := (a + b + c)/2.0;
        area := sqrt(s * (s - a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        writeln(area);     
    except
        on E: Exception do
            ShowMessage( 'Error: '+ E.ClassName + #13#10 + E.Message ); 
    end; 
end.
```

But it is giving following error:

```
$ fpc triangle_area.pas
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-11+deb9u1 [2017/06/10] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling triangle_area.pas
triangle_area.pas(14,2) Error: Identifier not found "try"
triangle_area.pas(15,3) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier READLN" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

Why "try" identifier is not being found. I am using fpc version 3.0.0 on Debian stable Linux.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `{$MODE OBJFPC}` or `{$MODE DELPHI}` beneath your program declaration.

The reason is that by default the compiler will compile in `MODE FPC`, which does not support exceptions.

Additional sources: [One](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse33.html) [Two](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progap4.html) [Three](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=37637.0)

On the other hand, the `ShowMessage` instruction will not compile with Free Pascal. The correct code is:

```
program TriangleArea;
{$mode delphi}
uses crt, sysutils;
type
    num = real;
var
  a, b, c, s, area : num;
begin
    write('Enter lengths of 3 sides (separated by spaces): ');
    try
        readln (a, b, c);
        s := (a + b + c)/2.0;
        area := sqrt(s * (s - a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        writeln(area);
    except
        on E: Exception do
            write( 'Error: '+ E.ClassName + #13#10 + E.Message );
    end;
end.
```

Later edit: the declaration `type num=real` is correct, but I don't see any real use of it.

Comment: Above code works with both `$MODE OBJFPC` and `$MODE DELPHI`, but `showMessage` does not work with either. How can I make `showMessage` work?